# Not able to connect to private docker repository

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I created Azure App Service (**docker Container**) and set PUBLISH for **Linux**. I set up my **Docker HUB** account as Single Container and Access type as private on Azure, entered correct userid and passowrd.

Post that, I am getting following error message in Container Setting's logs

> Pulling image from Docker hub: abc/xyz 2020-01-06 12:36:57.413 ERROR -
>   DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound,
>   response={"message":"pull access denied for abc/xyz, repository does
>   not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to
>   the resource is denied"}

If I change the repository to **Public** on docker hub and on Azure, changed access to **Public** then it works flawlessly.

What am I missing here? What additional settings are required on Azure

Comment: have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image#configure-registry-credentials-in-web-app?

Comment: @4c74356b41Pardon my ignorance with DevOps but I am trying to use Docker Hub , in that case, why would I need ACR?

Comment: it has a note about using docker hub, it really doesnt matter if you use docker hub or azure container registry, just the url changes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure the private docker hub registry and successfully pull my private docker repository. Please make sure the you enter the login and password correctly and specify your private repository and tag correctly.

[image]

I got the same error as yours when I entered a wrong password.

`2020-01-07 05:59:12.361 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: library/alpinelevi:v1
2020-01-07 05:59:12.728 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for alpinelevi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}`

Comment: Thanks for answering this, I did enter right user id and password. @Levi Lu-MSFT  Did you provide any access rights additionally?

Comment: Hi @JPM Did you enabled Two-Factor Authentication for your docker account? How was it going with this case?

Comment: @ Levi Lu-MSFT No, I did not. To try, I removed everything from DOcker Hub but added Docker hub entries in private registries(pointing to docker hub) and post that it suddenly worked. In the second attempt, it even worked with Docker Hub too. Thanks again for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

If the repo from where you are pulling the image is private then you need to do a docker login from the shell instance from where you are trying to pull the image.

Use `docker login` in shell and post that try the `docker pull abc/xyz`